# How can I control new tab action in react native WebView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I'm using react native WebView.

there is a problem when specific web pages.

**1. Normal behavior of mobile browser**

Clicking the Find Zip Code button will open a new tab, find and select an address, and the tab is automatically closed. The selected zip code is entered in a specific input box.

[image]

**2. Error of react native WebView**

If I click the Find Zip Code button, page open to the next page instead of the new tab. Finding zip code page does not automatically closed when I select address. because It is not a tab. if I press Back button completely leaves the order page.

[image]

I checked the function to call when clicking the Find Zip Code button on related homepage.

```
    function post_daum() {
        new daum.Postcode({
            oncomplete: function(data) {
                // 팝업에서 검색결과 항목을 클릭했을때 실행할 코드를 작성하는 부분.

                // 각 주소의 노출 규칙에 따라 주소를 조합한다.
                // 내려오는 변수가 값이 없는 경우엔 공백('')값을 가지므로, 이를 참고하여 분기 한다.
                var fullAddr = ''; // 최종 주소 변수
                var extraAddr = ''; // 조합형 주소 변수

                // 사용자가 선택한 주소 타입에 따라 해당 주소 값을 가져온다.
                if (data.userSelectedType === 'R') { // 사용자가 도로명 주소를 선택했을 경우
                    fullAddr = data.roadAddress;

                } else { // 사용자가 지번 주소를 선택했을 경우(J)
                    fullAddr = data.jibunAddress;
                }

                // 사용자가 선택한 주소가 도로명 타입일때 조합한다.
                if(data.userSelectedType === 'R'){
                    //법정동명이 있을 경우 추가한다.
                    if(data.bname !== ''){
                        extraAddr += data.bname;
                    }
                    // 건물명이 있을 경우 추가한다.
                    if(data.buildingName !== ''){
                        extraAddr += (extraAddr !== '' ? ', ' + data.buildingName : data.buildingName);
                    }
                    // 조합형주소의 유무에 따라 양쪽에 괄호를 추가하여 최종 주소를 만든다.
                    fullAddr += (extraAddr !== '' ? ' ('+ extraAddr +')' : '');
                }

                // 우편번호와 주소 정보를 해당 필드에 넣는다.
//                document.getElementById('sample6_postcode').value = data.zonecode; //5자리 새우편번호 사용
                document.getElementById('daum_add1').value = fullAddr;

                document.getElementById('daum_post1').value = data.zonecode.substr(0,3); //5자리 새우편번호 사용
                document.getElementById('daum_post2').value = data.zonecode.substr(3,2); //5자리 새우편번호 사용

                // 커서를 상세주소 필드로 이동한다.
                document.getElementById('daum_add2').focus();
            }
        }).open();
    }
```

Comment: target="_blank" not working on react-native-webview! I used react-native-custom-tabs instead of react-native-webview